# Walkthrough for Locally Linear Embedding

Tags: dimensionality-reduction

Can someone please walk me through the final step for LLE? Specifically, computing the coordinates of the vectors $Y_i$ on the lower dimensional manifold.

Disclaimer: I am aware of another post regarding LLE steps; however, it was largely inaccessible for me.

Comment: +1 Are you referring to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82037?

Comment: Yes, that's the one. @whuber